# How to fix the Imports Statement on Visual Studio 2008 for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, import

I am familiar with c# way of fixing the import via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>。</kbd> but how do you do this for visual basic project?

Also does visual basic does not seem to have the [Organize Using] feature for c#. If there is one can you please help.

Comment: I think VB might actually be missing these features. There's a lot of stuff that's available in C# projects but not in VB projects. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: I was hoping that VB might have placed it in a separate place or named differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the refactoring features available for C# do not exist in the VB.NET IDE.

They're not simply hidden somewhere or named something different. While the C# team was adding this stuff in, the VB.NET team was working on things like automatic background compilation. I expect they'll be added in a future version, but don't hold your breath.

You will have to install a third-party extension like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) if you require them.

But the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut still works fine. I'm nearly positive that Intellisense will still suggest importing namespaces when required, just like the C# IDE.

Comment: +1 if you use something in a namespace that isn't imported, the "quick fix" thingy will offer to import the namespace for you.